# Using React Native and Expo in VSCode, connectivity to Firestore on iOS not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

[Error Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekm5c.png)

[Possible Related Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4jlF.png)

When using expo with react my project runs fine on web and will access Firestore properly but when using iOS or iOS Simulators it will access firebase.auth() and use that correctly but says is unable to connect to Firestore.

Config File

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXX",
  appId: "1:XXXXXX:web:XXXXXXX"
};
```

Might have something to do with appId being something: web: something
If more code is needed I can make a repository just thought since it works perfect on web it doesn't have to do with anything except firebase config.

Comment: Can you share error message stack traces

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel I added a picture of the console error and call stack but if you think I need to provide anything more I can